# substring between two limit using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string, from this I have to obtain a substring between two limit using jQuery. For Example, my string is

```
var sel = "x<span class=\"fm-script fm-inline\" style=\"vertical-align: 1.33em;\"><span style=\"vertical-align: 0em;\"><span class=\"fm-vert fm-frac\">1/2</span></span></span>+y<span class=\"fm-script fm-inline\" style=\"vertical-align: 0.7em;\">3</span>+z<span class=\"fm-script fm-inline\" style=\"vertical-align: 1.33em;\"><span style=\"vertical-align: 0em;\"><span class=\"fm-vert fm-frac\">2/3</span></span></span>";
```

Now I need the value between `<span class=\"fm-script fm-inline\" style=\"vertical-align: 0.7em;\">` and `</span>`.

Here it is 3. The value is dynamic. Also the string `sel` contain more than one `<span class=\"fm-script fm-inline\" style=\"vertical-align: 0.7em;\">` and `</span>`. So i need all the value between these string.

How can I obtain this??

**I tried something like this:**

```
var item = sel.match("<span class=\"fm-script fm-inline\" style=\"vertical-align: 0.7em;\">(.*)</span>");
```

But this give the result between first(here only one) `<span class=\"fm-script fm-inline\" style=\"vertical-align: 0.7em;\">` and last `</span>`.

Please check the fiddle for more details: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/t1wtaojz/1/)

Here the desired output is 3. How can I achieve this? please help me..

Thank you..

Comment: Why not render it and use jQuery to grab the span content using selectors? Right now you do not use jQuery at all so the question is tagged wrong

Comment: I believe you're actually using just `Javascript` and not any `Javascript` library like `jQuery`.

Comment: please check the fiddle..and help me if you can..

Answer (score 0):

Why not render it and use jQuery to grab the span content using selectors? 
Running RegEx against HTML is considered a [BAD THING](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/295783)

```js
var getTextNodesIn = function(el) {
    return $(el).find(":not(iframe)").addBack().contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3;
    });
};
$(function() {
     var sel = "x<span class=\"fm-script fm-inline\" style=\"vertical-align: 1.33em;\"><span style=\"vertical-align: 0em;\"><span class=\"fm-vert fm-frac\">1/2</span></span></span>+y<span class=\"fm-script fm-inline\" style=\"vertical-align: 0.7em;\">3</span>+z<span class=\"fm-script fm-inline\" style=\"vertical-align: 1.33em;\"><span style=\"vertical-align: 0em;\"><span class=\"fm-vert fm-frac\">2/3</span></span></span>";
     
     var $myDiv = $("<div/>"),vals=[];
     $myDiv.append(sel.replace(/\\"/g,'"'));  
     var $nodes = getTextNodesIn($myDiv);    
     $nodes.each(function() {
         vals.push($(this).text());
     });
     alert(vals.join("\n"));
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions should do the trick:

```
var regex = new RegExp("<span class=\"fm-script fm-inline\" style=\"vertical-align: 0.7em;\">([^<]*)</span>","g");
var match = null;
while(match = regex.exec(sel)){
    console.log(match[1]);
}
```

Note: This assumes no other html tags exist within the spans.